# moodle The page isn't redirecting properly after intallation in xampp

Tags: xampp, moodle

I install Moodle on xampp server. its installed properly . but when I try to logout or any other activity Firefox shows error, **The page isn't redirecting properly**. I clear cookies of the browser but it didn't work. I reinstall Moodle but I got the same issue. How I can resolve this problem? anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following. It may help you to solve this issue.

1. Manually clear the cache in the Moodledata folder.
2. open admin/index.php file and comment the line
   redirect("index.php?sessionstarted=1&lang=$CFG->lang");

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue for err_too_many_redirects

Just Delete all data from moodledata folder ( C:\xampp\moodledata )

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=230067

Comment: Doesn't this remove any data as well as (hopefully) fix the issue? If so you should mention this fact in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I manually delete all files inside sitedata\cache
It is work for me

Answer (score -1):

This solved my issue with regards to redirecting of moodle.

1. navigate to: http://localhost/moodle/admin/settings.php?section=sessionhandling
2. on the page displayed you will see a field with a lable "Cookie prefix" in that field type "moodle"
3. Save Changes
4. type: http://localhost/moodle    to test

5.SMILE if it works :-) !!!

NB: This might not be the solution to everyone but try it.